# IPFS issue for number of peers count on WEBUI are shown zero

Tags: ipfs, private-network

I have setup a private network of IPFS using two machines A,B. In machine A I added the multi address of machine B and on Machine B I added the address of machine A now everything is running fine on both machines, I can add any file to machine A and get it on machine B, but the only problem is the webui of IPFS after setting up my private network the number of peers shown on webui are 0.

[See the image of webui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq147.png)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. [sf] is a better place for questions about network administration, and [unix.se] is the place for configuring Unix systems.